# call variable from while loop in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

> ```
> <?php
> // Create connection
> $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root");
> mysql_select_db("test") or die( "Unable to select database");
> if (mysqli_connect_errno())
>   {
>   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
>   }
>  
>  //***************************** table 1 detail ***********
>
> $query = "SELECT * FROM fraud WHERE a_number=" . $_GET["aNun_id"];
> echo "<title>" . $_GET["aNun_id"] . "</title>";         
> echo "<table width='50%' border='5'>
>       <tr>
>     <th>Date & Time</th>
>       <th>A Number</th>
>       <th>B Number</th>
>     <th>Status</th>
>       </tr>";       
>
> $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
> while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
> {
>   echo "<tr>";
>   echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
>   echo "<td>" . $row['a_number'] . "</td>";
>   echo "<td><a href='?bNun_id=".$row['b_number']."'>" . $row['b_number'] . "</a></td>";
>   echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
>   echo "</tr>";  
> }
> echo "</table>";
>  
> //***************************** table 2 detail ***********
>
> //Here i'm trying to use bNum_id in below query    
> $query = "SELECT * FROM fraud WHERE b_number=" . $_GET["bNun_id"];          
> echo "<table width='50%' border='5'>
>       <tr>
>     <th>Date & Time</th>
>       <th>A Number</th>
>       <th>B Number</th>
>     <th>Status</th>
>       </tr>"; 
>
> $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
>
> while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
> {
>   echo "<tr>";
>   echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
>   echo "<td>" . $row['a_number'] . "</td>";
>   echo "<td>" . $row['b_number'] . "</td>";
>   echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
>   echo "</tr>";  
> }
> echo "</table>";
>
> //connection close
> mysqli_close($con);
> ?>
> ```

Here in table one , I used **aNun_id** to get the data from another PHP file with "GET" command.
In the table two, I want **bNun_id** to show its related data in that table. How do i call **bNun _id** data to the second table from table one. Pls help me..

Comment: **WARNING:** your code is wide open to MySQL injection you should use either PDO/MySQLi with prepared statements or properly sanitize the data you're receiving before using it with your MySQL queries.

Comment: `$_GET["bNun_id"]` - typo?

Comment: Agreed with @Prix. And you have aNun_id instead of aNum_id all over

Comment: aNun_id & bNun_id are both different. aNum_id i use to get data from another PHP & bNun i used to get data from second table shows in the code.

Comment: my 1st table is working but my second table which is data from bNun_id is not working. i think the problem in the bNun_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those two tables in the same page? 
If so, You need to append the bNum_id to the same query string to use both aNum_id & bNum_id.

```
 echo "<td><a href='?aNun_id=".$_GET["aNun_id"]."&bNun_id=".$row['b_number']."'>" . $row['b_number'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: but start of the page it's take aNun_id from another PHP file & its creates a table. When i click on the data in the table that already created then its create another table. so i hav problem in the second table.. pls help me..